# How to replace values in dataframe in R with translation table with minimal computational time?

Tags: r, performance, for-loop, dataframe

I have the following biological data file.

```
#acgh_file   
chromosome startPosition
chr1 37196
chr1 52308
chr1 357503
chr1 443361
chr1 530358
```

and I need to convert the positions by means of a translation table.

```
#convert   
chr1    37196   chr1    47333
chr1    52308   chr1    62445
chr1    357503  chr1    367640
chr1    443361  chr1    453498
chr1    530358  chr1    540495
```

What needs to happen is that I have to replace the startPosition in the acgh_file with the value in fourth column of the convert table.

I made a script, but as the files are quite large it takes ages before it finishes (probably due to that R is not good for doing for-loops).

```
for (n in 1:nrow(convert)){
  acgh_file[acgh_file$chromosome==convert[n,1] & acgh_file$startPosition==convert[n,2],3] <- convert[n,4]
}
```

I'm looking for a quicker solution here. Anybody have some ideas? I thought about doing something with the apply functions, but I don't know how to combine that when using this convert look-up table that I have here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to use a `for-loop` here( Btw for loop in R are slow when they are not used in the good manner).  Here you want to do a `merge` between 2 data sets. Since you have a big data.frame, I suggest to use `data.table` package to do the merge.

```
library(data.table)
setkey(acgh_file,chromosome,startPosition)
setkey(convert_file,V1,V2)
acgh_file[convert_file] 
#    chromosome startPosition     V4
# 1:       chr1         37196  47333
# 2:       chr1         52308  62445
# 3:       chr1        357503 367640
# 4:       chr1        443361 453498
# 5:       chr1        530358 540495
```

where the data sets are data.table :

```
acgh_file    <- fread("
chromosome startPosition
chr1 37196
chr1 52308
chr1 357503
chr1 443361
chr1 530358")

convert_file <- fread("
chr1    37196   chr1    47333
chr1    52308   chr1    62445
chr1    357503  chr1    367640
chr1    443361  chr1    453498
chr1    530358  chr1    540495")[,V3:=NULL]
```

Comment: Awesome, this is very fast indeed. I should consider using this data.table format more often than the data.frame.